# fetch, JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как скрыть ошибку fetch, которая появляется в консоли?
catch не помогает

```js
fetch('fsfsd')
  .catch((err) => {
    // в данный момент ошибка уже выведена в консоли, почему-то
  
  })
```

Comment: Если вы про `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, то никак. Это не ответ от сервера, а обработка браузера.

Comment: вы **никак** не можете скрыть ошибку которую вернул сервер. Максимум просто очистить вывод консоли, но это является плохим решением, а так же не совсем понятно _зачем_

Comment: @Grundy, жалко, а как можно проверить соединение с сервером, чтобы никаких ошибок не выводилось?

Comment: @Юрий, никак, если сервер вернул ошибку - консоль ее покажет